# EE3 Channel Form with grid field

Tags: safecracker, ee3, grid

I'm trying to create fontend channel form page with a Grid field that has 3 columns.  I've tried different variations but don't seem to get it working correctly.  I have the css linked in my header

```
<link href="{path='css/_ee_channel_form_css'}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

The docs say to use

```
{field:my_field_name}
```

or if you are using {custom_fields} it says to use
    {if grid}
        {display_field}
    {/if}

But then it says "Manual construction of grid type fields is not supported. Most customization of grid fields can be done by overriding the CSS."

Comment: I think I narrowed it down to the fact that EE doesn't like jquery-3.1.1, because if I load jquery-1.11.2 the grid seems to work and has a "add new row" and then my fields show up.

Answer (score 0):

I added jQuery's migrate file so I could still use latest jQuery 3x and that seemed to solve the problem when using {field:my_field_name}. My Grid shows up now with functionality.  Some styling issues but seems to be working at least.

[jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js)